# OpenVPN (Focal/Jammy) is there any way to import a URL rather than use an ovpn file?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

Not being given an .ovpn file, I am instructed to import from a URL. Android and Windows and Mac have this choice. I don't mind the command line, but has anyone managed to do this?